# we have MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial) installed on Centos7

Tags: linux, mysql, centos7

I always have to start it manually on boot everything the server is down and boots up. Someone help me set it to start on boot with systemctl enable

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable mysqld

Failed to issue method call: Access denied

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mysqld

mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mysql

mysql.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql)

   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-10-26 10:18:16 EDT; 2 days ago
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
                ├─1485 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/trimdb03.pid
 └─2523 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --
plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-

error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.err --pid-file=/...

Oct 26 10:18:06 localhost systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...

Oct 26 10:18:16 localhost mysql[1244]: Starting MySQL......... SUCCESS!

Oct 26 10:18:16 localhost systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop MySQL.

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable mysql

mysql.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig mysql on

The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:

1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.

2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.

3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: What did vendor support say about this?

Comment: this is what the vendor support says. but my problem is, why cant systemd control it?                                                                                 Vendor: Can you run these commands and see if that helps resolve the issue?
chkconfig --del mysql
chkconfig --add mysql
chkconfig mysql on

Answer (score 1):

For some reason MySQL is using an old-style init script, even on CentOS 7, which uses systemd. They *should* have distributed a proper systemd unit file, but chose not to.

The proper way to enable an old-style init script is with `chkconfig`, i.e.:

```
chkconfig mysql on
```

If this *still* fails, then you need to get very loud and angry with your Oracle support contact.

Comment: chkconfig mysql on    works but does not redirect to systemctl which tells me they configured to work with the old style like you said.  thank you